# cmake how to partial static link, partial dynamic link?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a c++ project witch use mongodb as database.
I want to static link the mongodb driver.

I use this command to build the executable binary.

```
g++ -o ox one.cpp -pthread -Wall -std=c++11 \
-I /opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/ \
-I /opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/ \
-L /opt/mongo-cxx-driver/lib/ \
-L /opt/mongo-c-driver/lib/ \
-Wl,-Bstatic -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 \
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lgcc_s -lstdc++ -lcrypto -lssl -lrt
```

`ldd ox` reports that mongodb driver has been static linked

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd1a99d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7f8e4e0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7f8e15e000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f7f8dd19000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f7f8dab0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7f8d8a8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7f8d689000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7f8d2bf000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7f8cfb7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fc81736000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7f8cdb2000)
```

Now, I can simply copy the `ox` file to another computer (same os, same version) to use it.

But, My question is that, How to write rule in `CMakeList.txt`, to tell cmake which libraries I want to static link, which libraries I want to dynamic link ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna dynamically link a library, you must have a .so version of that library; likewise, if you wanna statically link a library, you must have a .a version of that library. Of course, this is for Linux like system